# Ant Design 5.0: Set properties of Tooltip in ConfigProvider

Tags: javascript, antd

is there a way to set a property for all ant design tooltips using the ThemeProvider? I tried doing it like this but it is not changing the property.

```
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    components: {
      Tooltip: {
        mouseEnterDelay: 0.5,
    },
  },
}}>
    <App />
</ConfigProvider>
```

I really don't want to create a custom tooltip component just to change the hover duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a global `mouseEnterDelay` configuration value on the `theme` prop. `ConfigProvider` doesn't support it. The `theme` prop is only used for setting the theme, not the component behavior. It only accepts the [design token](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#customize-design-token), `theme.components` is used only for setting the [custom component token](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#customize-component-token).

See [5.1.5/components/tooltip/index.tsx#L179](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/5.1.5/components/tooltip/index.tsx#L179)

```
// ...
const {
    getPopupContainer: getContextPopupContainer,
    getPrefixCls,
    direction,
  } = React.useContext(ConfigContext);
// ...
```

`Tooltip` component only uses these three configurations from `ConfigContext`. It uses the `mouseEnterDelay` prop from `props`, see [/5.1.5/components/tooltip/index.tsx#L267](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/5.1.5/components/tooltip/index.tsx#L267)

```
// ...
  const {
    getPopupContainer,
    placement = 'top',
    mouseEnterDelay = 0.1,
    mouseLeaveDelay = 0.1,
    overlayStyle,
    ...otherProps
  } = props;
// ...
```

I think it's ok to create your custom `Tooltip` component based on antd `Tooltip` component.

Comment: Too bad, but thanks for the information. Then I can create my own component with a good feeling :D

Comment: @somsam43 Creating our own common components and business component in our projects based on third-party components are very common. Or, you can think this is a customized process. If third-party components support the feature, it's cool. But not every feature will be considered.